# Finding an orthogonal vector by inspection

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

If I have a vector say:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
-\frac{1}{2} \\
1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

How can I identify a vector orthogonal to this by inspection?
For example if I have this vector:
$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
1 
\end{bmatrix}
$ I know that $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}$ is orthogonal.

So if I change the the sign of the third entry of the initial vector of interest such that it now looks like this:
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
-\frac{1}{2} \\
-1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Would that suffice to be orthogonal? Is there a general rule to use here?

Comment: oops, I should know that i can just take the dot-product of these two vectors to confirm. Braindead moment. Cheers.

Comment: Vectors $u,v\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ are orthogonal if $u^{\top}v=0$. For your case, any vector $v=[v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}]^{\top}$ that satisfies $v_{1}+\frac{v_{2}}{2}-v_{3}=0$ will work. An example is $[1,0,1]^{\top}$

Comment: yep, thanks @nemo for your help.

Comment: That's great @nemo, thanks.

Comment: Sure, no problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your example : $(-1,-1/2,1)$ , choose, for example, $(-1/2,1,0).$

The scalar  product: $(-1)(-1/2) + (-1/2)1 + 0 =0.$

Scalar product:

$\vec A:= (a,b,c) \ne 0$, $ \vec B =(d,e,f) \ne 0$, then:

$\vec A \cdot \vec B =$

$(a,b,c) \cdot (d,e,f) =$

$ad + be +cf  = 0$,

$\rightarrow$ the 2 vectors are orthogonal.

See also:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product

Comment: Thanks for your help @PeterSzilas

Comment: Anytime, welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You've found a way to make two of the terms of the dot product sum to zero — what you need to do is also make the rest of the terms of the dot product sum to zero, so that the overall sum is zero.

$(-\frac{1}{2} ) \cdot (-\frac{1}{2}) \neq 0$, so that doesn't work; your dot product is nonzero.

Fortunately, this has an easy solution: those components to zero in the vector you're constructing.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Hurkyl